# drawBitmap context.getResource null

Tags: android, canvas, nullpointerexception, android-context

Hi I'm triying to set an image using Bitmap but I have a **Null point exception** in my context.

This is my code.

```
public class Helper extends Activity {
//my code
private static Helper  _instance;

    public Helper() {
        _instance = this;
    }                                 

    public static Context getContext() {
        return _instance;
    }
//code
private static void draw(Canvas canvas, String letters, int tileColor,
            int textColor, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
//code
            canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_instance.getResources(),
            R.drawable.wine), (right + left) / 2 - width / 2, (top + bottom)
            / 2 + rect.height() / 2, null);

}
```

What I'm doing wrong? my error is in **_instance.getResources()**

Comment: where do you create a new `Helper`

Comment: Do you mean Helper h = new helper();? I'm not doing  that.

Comment: then that is why `_instance` is null

Comment: So before use _instance I need do Helper h = new helper(); and then use h.getResources()?

Comment: well yeah, when you dont initialize something that object is null in any language

Comment: Not any language, it could be a random value instead (would be in C or C++).  But either one is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, static references to a Context are GIANT memory leaks.  Nor is this needed-  since helper extends Activity, you can just call getResources directly.

Comment: I still have the same error. java.Lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89) and this is now my code  Helper h = new Helper();
  canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(h.getResources(), R.drawable.wine), (right + left) / 2 - width / 2, (top + bottom)
    / 2 + rect.height() / 2, null);

Answer (score 0):

I  solved my error just adding ***Context*** in my method.

```
    private static void draw(Canvas canvas, String letters, int tileColor,
                int textColor, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Context context) {
                   //my code

}
```

Thanks you guys

Comment: You can "accept" your own answer by clicking on the green tick. This removes it from the pool of unanswered questions on StackOverflow.